# How to add an array formula for updates

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm working on trying to add an array formula so that the status column updates as information is entered.

This is an order tracking sheet. When an order is entered get set to Available, Once a driver is assigned change the status to Dispatched. As times are entered in the In and Out columns to change from Picked to Delivered. Finally once its checked off as Billed to mark the status as Complete.

So far I've only gotten to
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(D3:D&H3:H&I3:I&M3:M&N3:N)=0, "Available", IF(D3:D<>"", "Dispatched")))

I haven't been able to figure out past that.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13tOkLwtPYyWm9rUfkCidqwUygzFfVfmIzV-EwL5i7hM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure which column was used to mark billed, so I just guess column P, just change it to the proper column.  Enter this formula in row 1 of your status column.

```
={"Status";
   ARRAYFORMULA(
    IFERROR(
     IFS(
      P2:P<>"", "Complete",
      J2:J<>"", "Delivered",
      I2:I<>"", "Picked",
      E2:E<>"", "Dispatched"
      ), 
    "")
   )}
```

Explanation
Starting inside and working out:

- The ranges J2:J, etc,  tell the array formula which column to evaluate as it goes row by row, starting at row 2, and ending at the bottom of the sheet.
- The IFS formula checks condition:result pairs,  If the first condition is met, it displays that value, but if not, it goes to the next one, and so on until it finds a condition that is true or reaches the end.
- The IFS formula will return an error if it doesn't find any of the conditions to be true, so the IFERROR says to leave the cell blank if there are no true conditions.
- The ARRAYFORMULA evaluates each row for the defined range.
- The { xxxx ; xxxxxxx}stacks the items after the semicolon below the item before the semicolon.  In this usage, the label "Status" is in row 1, and the results are in the rows below it.  This ensures that no one accidentally sorts or erases the formula.